# Changing PHP code to inbetween

Tags: php

the following code will add 1 to the current price in an auction script.

i want to replace all of the related stuff with a simple form

if x is any number between 100 and 500
then add 10 to x

if x is any number between 501 and 1000
then add 20 to x

by x i mean current price after any one bid
something like this picture

[img] http://www.premiumpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/increments1.jpg [/img]

the problem is that i'm not a coder nor a programmer. :(

so any help will be great

thanks folks

```
// BIDDING AND MAKE OFFER
            case "newbid": {                

                if(!is_numeric($_POST['bidamount'])){

                    // LEAVE MSG 
                    $GLOBALS['error_message'] = str_replace("%a", $_POST['bidamount'] ,$CORE->_e(array('auction','29')));   

                }else{

                    //1. GET ANY CURRENT BIDDING DATA
                    $current_bidding_data = get_post_meta($post->ID,'current_bid_data',true);
                    if(!is_array($current_bidding_data)){ $current_bidding_data = array(); }

                    //2. ORDER IT BY KEY (WHICH HOLDS THE BID AMOUNT)
                    krsort($current_bidding_data);

                    // 3. SWITCH THE BID TYPE TO PERFORM ACTIONS        
                    switch($_POST['bidtype']){

                        // BIDDING SYSTEM
                        case "bid": {

                            // GET THE CURRENT PRICE
                            $current_price = get_post_meta($post->ID,'price_current',true);

                            // CHECK IF THE BID AMOUNT IS GREATER THAN THE EXISTINT CURRENT PRICE
                            if( $_POST['bidamount'] > $current_price ){

                                    // LETS CHECK IF WE HAVE A BIGGER AMOUNT THAN THE BIDDERS TOTAL
                                    $checkme = current($current_bidding_data);

                                    // OLD BIDDER IS STILL WINNER                                    
                                    if(is_numeric($current_price) && $current_price > 0 && isset($checkme) && ( $checkme['max_amount'] >=  $_POST['bidamount']) ){

                                        $is_new_bid = false;

                                        if($_POST['bidamount'] == $checkme['max_amount']){
                                        $current_price = $_POST['bidamount'];
                                        }else{
                                        $current_price = $_POST['bidamount']+1;
                                        }

                                        $GLOBALS['error_message'] = $CORE->_e(array('auction','30'));   

                                    // NEW BIDDER IS WINNER
                                    }else{  

                                        $is_new_bid = true;

                                        // EMAIL THE OLD BIDDER AND LET THEM KNOW THEY HAVE BEEN OUTBID 
                                        if(isset($checkme['userid']) && $checkme['userid'] != $userdata->data->ID){
                                        $_POST['username']  = $checkme['username']; 
                                        $_POST['title']     = $post->post_title;    
                                        $_POST['link']      = get_permalink($post->ID);                              
                                        $CORE->SENDEMAIL($checkme['userid'],'auction_outbid');
                                        }

                                        // NOW SET NEW PRICE
                                        if($current_price == "" || $current_price == "0"){
                                            $current_price = 1;                                         
                                        }elseif(isset($checkme['max_amount'])){                                             
                                            $current_price = $checkme['max_amount']+1;                                               
                                        }else{
                                            $current_price++;
                                        }

                                        $GLOBALS['error_message'] = $CORE->_e(array('auction','31'));   

                                    }
                            }   

                            // UPDATE THE LISTING WITH THE NEW CURRENT PRICE                        
                            update_post_meta($post->ID,'price_current', $current_price);                        

                        } break;                        

                    }

                    //3. ADD ON THE NEW BID 
                    if($is_new_bid){            

                    $current_bidding_data[$_POST['bidamount']] = array( 'max_amount' =>$_POST['bidamount'], 'userid' => $userdata->data->ID, 'username' => $userdata->data->user_nicename, 'date' => current_time( 'mysql' ), 'bid_type' => $_POST['bidtype']  );                       

                    //4. MERGE THE TWO AND SAVE
                    update_post_meta($post->ID,'current_bid_data', $current_bidding_data);  

                    }                 

                    //5. ADD LOG ENTRY
                    $CORE->ADDLOG("<a href='(ulink)'>".$userdata->user_nicename.'</a> bid on the listing <a href="(plink)"><b>['.$post->post_title.']</b></a>.', $userdate->ID, $post->ID ,'label-info');

                    //6. UPDATE USER META TO INDICATE THEY BID ON THIS ITEM             
                    $user_bidding_data = get_user_meta($userdata->data->ID,'user_bidding_data',true);
                    if(!is_array($user_bidding_data)){ $user_bidding_data = array(); }
                    $user_bidding_data[] = array('postid' => $post->ID, 'max_amount' =>$_POST['bidamount'], 'date' => current_time( 'mysql' ), 'bid_type' => $_POST['bidtype'], 'title' => $post->post_title);
                    update_user_meta($userdata->data->ID,'user_bidding_data',$user_bidding_data);

                } 
            } break;

        }// end switch  
    }// end if  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (x < 100 || x > 1000{//do nothing}
elseif (x < 501){x += 10;}
else{x += 20}
```